# Find a way to reward people that answer 1 rep questions

Tags: feature-request

I was looking in the top people list for Lua tag in stackoverflow, and noticed that I have 3 of reputation coming from that, but several answers, some that someone confirmed that it is correct...

The thing is: I am getting tired of wasting time replying ANY question with 1 rep, because although I noticed this first with Lua, there almost any question that I reply with a 1 rep user, the user never accept it, and noone ever upvote it, even when there are comments indicating the reply was good...

So I think a feature is needed to reward people that take time to reply to 1 rep people, because frankly, click on some less popular tags (ie: not java) and you will see loads of 0 answers questions with 1 rep asker.

Comment: I would say that you're aiming in the wrong direction. This is a meta-XY problem. It's not about "1-rep questions". It's about low-visibility tags. The reason you don't get many upvotes is because those tags don't have a lot of visitors.

Comment: I realized that and made a second post...

Answer (score 3):

This seems a little backwards; it's the user(s) that choose not to participate in the SO norms that should be reminded about SO's cultural mores. (IMO only, most people disagree with me on this.)

People answering questions do so of their own accord, and must accept that their answer might be accepted, might not, might be downvoted (perhaps even maliciously), upvoted, ignored, etc.

Comment: Yes, so people sometimes might decide to stop answering at all... And this might results in tags without useful things.

Comment: @speeder Such is life--tag survival depends on both people asking, and answering. If nobody asks or answers, the tag gets ignored, SO goes on.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I thought `Tenacious` and `Unsung Hero` badges can be rewarding for users who actually prefer to help newcomers. ) As these users still can accept your answer, but even after that probably won't be able to upvote immediately. And they may well forget to return to their question later, when they - probably - will accumulate a required reputation.

Of course, the real question is how to persuade them to accept your answer instead of leaving the 'thank you' comments under it. Sometimes a well-placed comment might help. )

But then again, what exactly do you propose to reward? Any answers given to 1-rep questions? That, I'm afraid, will provoke a wave of trash (but not 'downvotable' trash, if you know what I mean :) ) and, by the way, will discriminate all the other OPs.

How about reverting it - and trying to make *the questions* useful, instead of answers? I know, it can be hard, but it can be rewarding - even though enough time should pass to make the difference probably. )